# Prevent Windows thread (_beginThread) from taking up too much CPU?

Tags: visual-c++, cpu-usage

I used one of the minimise to tray VC++ examples to create a program that would pop up a message at intervals to remind me to rest my eyes.

The program goes like this:

```
  startTime = time(0);
  g_hInstance=hInstance;

  HWND hWnd=CreateDialog(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),NULL,DialogProc);
  if(hWnd)
  {
    MSG msg;
    _beginthread(&checkEyeRestTime, 0, 0);  
    while(GetMessage(&msg,hWnd,0,0))
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
```

and the checkEyeRestTime function:

```
void checkEyeRestTime(void* ptr)
{
    while( true )
    {
     //logic to check time and display message
    }//while

    _endthread();
}
```

But this program takes up 50% CPU on a two core processor. How can I reduce the load on the processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [timer event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of the polling loop.

Comment: Thanks. It's what I was considering, but I had wanted to know how to prevent a simple while loop from taking up so much of CPU. Obviously the timer is also polling internally. How did they manage it? Guess I'll search for some source code of the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Or insert Sleep(0) in the thread. This allows other threads to get some time.

If this does not help, you can increase sleep time.

Comment: I had eventually used `Sleep(numberOfSeconds*1000);`